# Rxjs synchronous?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I recently started working on a new project and I have seen this twice now, am I crazy or will never work under any circumstance?

```js
protected get reportView(): any {
    let convertedView = null;
    this.store
      .pipe(select(fromStore.getTransferOrderConverted), rxjs.take(1))
      .subscribe((convertedOrder) => (convertedView = convertedOrder));
    return convertedView;
  }
```

Comment: One of the main unwritten rules of observables: subscribe where you need the information. So in your case, you'd need to return the observable from the function and subscribe to it where it's response is required.

Answer (score 3):

> am I crazy or will never work under any circumstance?

Q) Are you crazy?
A) Yes. Absolutely. That looks bonkers!

Q) Will this never work under any circumstance?
A) Oh, there are times this will work. Some observables are synchronous.

For example, this will always log a `2`, so this works as expected.

```ts
let convertedView = null;

of(1).pipe(
    map(v => v + 1)
).subscribe(convertedOrder => convertedView = convertedOrder);

console.log(convertedView);
```

That's because `of(1)` is a synchronous observable.

---

This, however, will never work

```ts
let convertedView = null;

of(1).pipe(
    delay(0),
    map(v => v + 1)
).subscribe(convertedOrder => convertedView = convertedOrder);

console.log(convertedView);
```

This will print `null`. Even though `delay(0)` conceptually takes no time, it still uses JSs event loop and therefore doesn't get executed until the current code completes.

---

I think it's best practise to assume all `observables` are asynchronous. Any code that assume otherwise is likely to be brittle.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea that " Some observables are synchronous".

Comment: 'I think it's best practise to assume all observables are asynchronous."
I came here with the opposite problem.
In assuming that all observables are asynchronous, I wrote this

const subscription = someObservable.subscribe(() => {
    ...
    subscription.unsubscribe();
})

/that/ is a ReferenceError.  The code ran synchronously so subscription will be assigned /after/ the anonymous function.  This pipe(delay(0)) looks like the right way to handle this.

Comment: @JoelRoberts You're right. But `delay(0)` is a poor way to handle this problem. You can always find an equivalent operator that will work regardless of synchronicity. Use that instead. :)

Comment: @MrkSef As far as I know, I'm not using any particular complicated operator, just subscribe.  If you think I should avoid delay, please put me to the recommended operator to ensure asynchronous execution.

Comment: @JoelRoberts, if you're unsubscribing to the observable you've just subscribed to, you've almost certainly missed a declarative operator that will work regardless of synchronicity. You shouldn't need to ensure asynchronous execution. I don't know what you're doing, so I can't help further. `take`, `takeWhile`, and `takeUtil` all come to mind, but it depends.

Answer (score 1):

Your `store.subscribe` is asynchronous and the rest of your code is not.
You can resolve it with a Promise like the example below.

```
protected get reportView(): Promise < any > {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.store
            .pipe(select(fromStore.getTransferOrderConverted), rxjs.take(1))
            .subscribe((convertedOrder) => resolve(convertedOrder));
    });
}

reportView.then(convertedOrder => {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Also you can get the convertedOrder with [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). But remember, the parent function must be `async`.

```
const convertedOrder = await reportView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert a stream to synchronous isn't a good ideal.
However, you can use method `toPromise` of a subject (subscription) for convert it to a promise and await for resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Rxjs take(1), first() operator should work absolutely fine

These 2 operators takes the latest value from store selector or BehaviourSubject in synchronous way.